# Java String Sorting Errors

Tags: java, string, sorting, polymorphism

I am trying to read in strings and sort them.  I have received many errors, which are starred in the below code.  Can you tell me how to fix those errors?

```
package hw05;

/*
Demonstrates selectionSort on an array of strings.
*/
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Strings {
    // --------------------------------------------
    // Reads in an array of strings, sorts them,
    // then prints them in sorted order.
    // --------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] stringList;
        String size;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nHow many strings do you want to sort? ");
        size = scan.nextLine();
        **stringList = new String[size];**

        System.out.println("\nEnter the strings...");
        **for (String i = 0; i < size; i++)
            stringList[i] = scan.nextLine();**
        Sorting.selectionSort(stringList);

        System.out.println("\nYour strings in sorted order...");
        **for (String i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.print(stringList[i] + " ");**
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stringList = new String[size];
```

size should be `int` not `String`. You need to do something like below:

```
int sizeInInt = Integer.valueOf(size); // This may throw NumberFormatException, wrap it in try/catch.

stringList = new String[sizeInInt ];
```

(or)

Change size to `int` and do `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`

I would suggest do hasNext() before doing either nextInt() (or) nextLine() otherwise you may get `NoSuchElementException`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should post the exact errors that you get.

With that said, take a look at this part of each line:

```
String i = 0
```

Here you declare a `String` variable named `i` and assign it the value `0` which is an `int`. The compiler complains because you are assigning a value of a different type to the variable.

This may not be the only problem with your code. As I said earlier, please post the error messages so we can help you in a more timely manner.

Comment: Here is the error I get when I run it.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types
  required: int
  found:    java.lang.String
 at hw05.Strings.main(Strings.java:25)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @MaggieErwin How are you compiling and running your code? I'm very surprised that you can run it because it shouldn't even compile.